# Start using Helvetia

Tags: dsl, pharo

I am willing to start embedding my language into Helvetia, but i dont really know where to start. 
Some weeks ago i wrote the parsing part using Petit Parser.
I would like to embed code similar to the following, like the sql example in Helvetia page:

```
main ()
{
Put(Red)
Move(North)
}
```

I look forward some guide more simple :P than the Helvetia examples

Answer (score 2):

There are various examples included with the distribution of Helvetia that do exactly what you are asking for and that you might want to study:

- `Cutie-Helvetia-Automaton` uses the low-level Helvetia infrastructure to integrate an automaton language defined in `CUAutomatonGrammar`.
- `Cutie-LanguageBoxes-SQL` uses the high-level language boxes infrastructure to embed SQL defined in `LBSqlGrammar` into Smalltalk.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into

http://scg.unibe.ch/research/helvetia

particularly the publications in the SCG link on Language Boxes (6) and Embedding Languages without breaking tools (&) explain how to use helvetia in more detail

http://www.lukas-renggli.ch/blog/phd-defended